# Node Js MongoDb Error "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i am beginner of node js and mongodb.when i tried to add the add via postman to mongodb i ran into the problem.
**{
"code": "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE"
}**

what i tried so far i attached below.i added all the files along with the mongodb connection.and i attached the model as well

**routes**

```
router.route('/user/getAll').get(userController.getDataConntrollerfn);
```

**userController.js**

```
var createUserControllerFn = async (req, res) => 
{
    const userModelData = new userModel(req.body)
    try
    {
        await userModelData.save()

        res.status(201).send(userModel);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        res.status(400).send(error);
    }


}
```

**userModel.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
  

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('employees', userSchema);
```

**mongodb**

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/est",{useNewUrlParser: true,  useUnifiedTopology: true },function checkDB(error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        console.log("errorr")
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("DB Connectedddd!!!!!!!!!!!")
    }
});

server.use(cors());
server.use(express.json());
server.use(routes);
server.use(bodyParser.json());

server.listen(8040,function check(error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        console.log("errorr")
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("startedddddd")
    }
});
```

**userModel.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
  
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('employees', userSchema);
```

Comment: Can you post mongo DB connection file?

Comment: i updateddddddddddddddddd

Comment: express.json() and bodyParser.json() both mean same remove one of these. Also let me know are you getting this message on console "DB Connectedddd!!!!!!!!!!!"?

Comment: db is connected no problem

Comment: db connection workinggggg

Comment: DB Connectedddd successfully.when i add the data via the postman get above errror

Comment: Can you please also update how you are importing userModel in controller ?

Comment: ok i will updateeeeee it.

Comment: Please log the full error, not just its JSON representation. Also, your keyboard is broken, it's repeating a lot of characters.

Comment: i got this error on postman  body  when i create the record  {
    "code": "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE"
}

Comment: Yes, and that error isn't very useful. You need to log the error in your code (`console.log(error)`) and check the server log to see where exactly it gets thrown.

Comment: Are you passing request body in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
const userModelData = new userModel(req.body)
try
{
    await userModelData.save()

    res.status(201).send(userModel);
}
catch(error)
{
    res.status(400).send(error);
}
```

With this and try:

```
try
{
    const body = req.body
    const userModelData = new userModel()
    userModelData.name = body.name
    userModelData.address = body.address
    userModelData.phone = body.phone
    await userModelData.save()

    const user=await userModel.findOne({phone: body.phone})

    res.status(200).send({message: "success", user: user});
}
catch(error)
{
    res.status(400).send(error);
}
```

Comment: thanks sir. works . only displayed   message: "success"  only . i need to display  message: "success" and record add successfully how

Comment: Good to know that, mongo don't provide created record. You need to make one more query for that and pass it in JSON response.

Comment: JSON response. how to pass sir. like   stauts {    message : "success"  }  like that way on post man

Comment: Let me update it for you.

Comment: i have got it sir thanks. if you good at react js please answer this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75519164/react-jsx-dropdown-calcultation-not-working/75519586#75519586

Comment: Now make sure your phone is unique in DB and it should be as of rules.

Comment: Sure, let me try.

Comment: have you tried that link sir