# React JSX DropDown Calcultation not working

Tags: reactjs

i am begineer of react js.i am creating simple react inventory.it consist of GR and KR Calculation.i have done design well not when i enter the qty and select gr or kr i didn't get any outputs. what i tried so far i attached below.if i select as gr i need to calculate gr calculation and select as kr calculate kr calculation.

```
import { useState } from "react";

function ChickenShop() {
  const [selects, setSelects] = useState();
  const [qty, setQty] = useState();
  var amount;
  function Calculation() {
    

   if(selects.onChange == "1")
   {
     amount = qty * 140 ;
   
   }
   else
   {
     amount = qty /1000 * 140 ;

   }

  }

  return (
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Chicken Shop Inventory</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Qty</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Salary"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setQty(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Type</label>
        <select
          class="form-control"
          value={selects} onChange={(event) => {
            setSelects(event.target.value); }}
          required
        >
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">GR</option>

          <option value="2">KG</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Total</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Net Salary"
          value={ amount }
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" onClick={Calculation} class="btn btn-primary mt-4">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChickenShop;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't edit my previous answer; hence, I am posting a second answer.
If you just want to display the total amount, you won't need to store it in a state variable; you can also calculate and display it on the fly like here:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function ChickenShop() {
  const [selects, setSelects] = useState('GR');
  const [qty, setQty] = useState();

  function calculation() {

    if (!qty) { return 0; }
    else if(selects == "GR") { return (qty * 140) ;}
    else { return (qty /1000 * 140 );}
  }

  return (

    <div className="container">
      <h3>Chicken Shop Inventory</h3>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Qty</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Salary"
          onChange={(event) => {setQty(event.target.value);}}
        />
      </div>

      <div className="form-group">
        <label>Type</label>
        <select
          className="form-control"
          value = {selects}
          onChange={(event) => {setSelects(event.target.value); }}
        >
          <option value="GR">GR</option>
          <option value="KG">KG</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <p>Total: {calculation()}<br/>
        Selected: {selects}<br />
        Quantity: {qty}</p>

    </div>
  );
}

export default ChickenShop;
```

In other words, just call the function calculation() from within the JSX, wherever you would like to display the amount.

Answer (score 0):

`amount` needs to be a state variable, too. Put simply, you need to use useState to initialise it:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function ChickenShop() {
  const [selects, setSelects] = useState();
  const [qty, setQty] = useState();
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(0);


  function Calculation() {


    if(selects.onChange == "1")
    {
      setAmount(qty * 140) ;

    }
    else
    {
      setAmount(qty /1000 * 140 );

    }

  }

  return (
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Chicken Shop Inventory</h3>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Qty</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Enter Salary"
          onChange={(event) => {
            setQty(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Type</label>
        <select
          class="form-control"
          value={selects} onChange={(event) => {
          setSelects(event.target.value); }}
          required
        >
          <option value="">Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">GR</option>

          <option value="2">KG</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Total</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Net Salary"
          value={ amount }
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" onClick={Calculation} class="btn btn-primary mt-4">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ChickenShop;
```

If you define `var amount`: The function Chickenshop() is called every time the component rerenders. That means the variable `amount` will be set back to `undefined` many times - for every change on the component. Hence, the value of `amount` will probably not be what you expect.

Within the JSX, only changes in state variables will update the DOM. React doesn't recognise changes of a 'plain' variable.

Comment: tried this code but no output

Comment: is this dropdown call correct

Comment: I have tested the code, it works fine for me. Do you mean with 'no output' that the amount is not displayed after clicking the submit button, or that the component doesn't render at all?

The select tag (the dropdown) is correct, but I would remove this line: `<option value="">Please Select</option>`. Also, you don't need to use an input field to display the calculated amount, you could use for example: `<p>Total: {amount}</p>`

Comment: i did what you said but no output displayed sir

Comment: error display on the console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onChange')

Comment: It sounds like that something went wrong with copying and pasting the code...
I've posted a second answer and shortened the code a bit - please have a try.